# How to Create Sound Object Dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3

How to create sound object dynamically in one movieClip.

Example

```
for(i=1;i<5;i++){var sound + i = new Sound();}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting all the sounds from your loop inside an Array:

```
var soundArray:Array = [];
for (var i:uint = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var sound:Sound = new Sound(); 
    // don't forget to set the path of the file you want to play

    soundArray.push(sound);
}
```

To play the the sound, all you need to do is take note of the index:

```
Sound(soundArray[0]).play();
```

Hope this helps.

irot

Answer (score 0):

you need a MovieClip to store your sounds into then:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
for( var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    mc[ 'sound_' + i ] = new Sound(); 
}
```

to access a sound, you can then call:

```
mc[ 'sound_0' ].play();
```

if you're already in the scope of a MovieClip, ignore the mc creation and replace 'mc' with 'this' in the loop.